# Did Android Studio 3.6.1 remove the connection assistant?

Tags: android-studio

A young friend of mine would like to push a game created using www.buildbox.com to his Samsung Android Tablet. He is using Windows 10 and Android Studio 3.6.1.

But the Device Drop Down is greyed out and for some reason the AVD Manager, the SDK Manager and the **Connection Assistant** are missing from this tools menu.

On my Android Studio 3.4 I can still see the **Connection Assistant**

I checked the Release notes but could not find anything.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases

I checked that Windows can see the tablet as a USB device and the friend told me that developer mode is enabled.

Any ideas what is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

So I got a chance to look further into the problem.
It turned out, that the problem seems to be with Buildbox not generating a proper Android project. In particular the generated project is missing a proper module and a proper app configuration. Once I added those the missing connection tool reappeared.

However I still got an error.[image]